# Extracting complete current line from std::istream

Tags: c++, istream, istringstream, istream-iterator

I am scanning text coming from a `std::istream`. The scanning is already under way, and I would like to extract the line that is currently being read (from beginning to end). This `getCurrentLine()` function must not modify the `std::istream` position.

I wrote this piece of code, which I find rather messy. Is there a better way to do this? (`charStream_` is the `std::istream`)

```
std::string Scanner::getCurrentLine() const {
  auto pos = charStream_.tellg();

  // rewind until beginning of the line or stream
  while (charStream_.peek() != '\n' && charStream_.tellg() != 0)
    charStream_.unget();

  // consume endline character
  if (charStream_.peek() == '\n')
    charStream_.get();

  std::stringstream lineStream;
  char c;
  do {
    c = static_cast<char>(charStream_.get());
    lineStream << c;
  } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);

  charStream_.seekg(pos);

  return lineStream.str();
}
```

Comment: Something wrong with using `getline` instead of that do-while loop?

Comment: makes sense. That will clean up at least that part.

Answer (score 0):

use the function *std::getline(std::cin, std::string)*

Comment: will getline return the line from the beginning or starting at the current `std::istream` position?